# Laravel Unit Testing - How to check Validation Rules or classes?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I'm doing a school project and we have to submit some unit testing examples . I read many tutorials but having trouble understanding how to use it .

This is my code below ,

I'm trying to check my validation rules by manual input :

```
<?php



class Student {

    public static $rules = array(

    'username'=>'required|alpha_num|min:6',

    'firstname'=>'required|alpha|min:2',

    'lastname'=>'required|alpha|min:2',

    'studentid'=>'numeric|min:7|unique:student',

    'email'=>'required|email|unique:student',

    'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',

    'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'

    );



}

class ChronosTest extends TestCase {

    public function testUser()
    {

        $student = new Student;

        //$student->username = "john433";



        $validator = Validator::make(array("username"=>"john433", "firstname"=>"johne"), Student::$rules);

        $this->assertTrue($validator->passes());



    }

}
```

I get this everytime i use assertTrue :

[image: att]
<sub>(source: [4.ii.gl](http://4.ii.gl/sTeWIK.png))</sub>

I get this everytime i use assertFalse :

[image: att]
<sub>(source: [1.ii.gl](http://1.ii.gl/y3il6n.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue - It was returning false everytime as i did not include all the required inputs such as passwords etc..

The following works properly :

```
$validator = Validator::make(array(
    "username"=>"john433",
    "firstname"=>"john",
    "lastname"=>"doe",
    "email"=>"johnerr@gmail.com",
    "password"=>"passtest",
    "password_confirmation"=>"passtest"
), Student::$rules);
```

Comment: Hey, Just came across this. May want to mark this as the "Answer" so that is shows up as such under searches. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to test is Laravel code. One simply does not want to test code that he/her didn't write him/herself. Try finding a new example. Also; static attributes are very hard to test because they cannot be mocked. I guess you still have a lot to learn. Here's a good write-up on how to write tests and what to test: https://medium.com/laravel-4/48414f4782d0